# .NET REST API with Vert.x

Tags: java, c#, rest, microservices, vert.x

I have a .NET REST API application that read some data from active directory.

I want to build a microservices based environment and decide to use http://vertx.io/ that is written in java. Vert.x support different language except for .NET application.

My question is, how can I deploy a .NET REST API application to Vert.x that I can communicate with other Vert.x based services. As far I understood, Microservices environment provide you to programming in different languages.

Answer (score 2):

During 2016 Google summer of code one of the students implemented several bridges to interconnect non vertx applications with vertx event bus. There is a C# implementation here: https://github.com/jaymine/TCP-eventbus-client-C-Sharp that will allow you to use .net applications with vertx.